# Getting bootstrap-multiselect to work with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

Can't get bootstrap-multiselect (http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect) to work with Angular2+. As far I can see everything is installed correctly:

`packages.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  (...)
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "bootstrap-multiselect": "^0.9.13-1",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
}
```

`angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
]
```

But when I load the application in a browser I get an error:

```
TypeError: $ is undefined
./node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js/<
bootstrap-multiselect.js:1388
./node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js
bootstrap-multiselect.js:44
__webpack_require__
./src/app/tasks/tasks.component.ts
__webpack_require__
./src/app/app.module.ts
__webpack_require__
./src/main.ts
__webpack_require__
[0]
__webpack_require__
checkDeferredModules
webpackJsonpCallback
```

My guess is that webpack takes scripts to create bundle in wrong order. It should put jQuery before bootstrap-multiselect, but instead it puts it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

It could be indeed a webpack issue. In my experience it is always easier to use a package that was packed in a way so that it is ready to be used by angular.

There is a package called [angular2dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect) .

Would it be an option for you to use this package or is bootstrap-multiselect a hard requirement for your use case?

Comment: It is an option to consider. Nontheless it is worth noting that this issue can come up with many other libraries so it would be nice to know the answer how to solve my problem without using libraries dedicated to angular.